# show layout as view while performing api request

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, view

im trying to show view layout which it's xml layout while performing api request and remove it after the request is done the layout contains TextView and animation and after the layout is showing i need to set TextView to random text

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#091A24">

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/loading_splashscreenText"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/lottiLoadingProgress"
    app:lottie_loop="true"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loading_splashscreenText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:fontFamily="@font/outfitsemibold"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Loading ... "
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here's my layout and i need to access the textview by its id after the layout is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <!--Keep your layout here-->
        
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#77000000">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/loading_splashscreenText"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/lottiLoadingProgress"
            app:lottie_loop="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loading_splashscreenText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:background="@color/ColorBlack"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Loading ... "
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

API Function

```
           private void callAPI() {
            RLProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Interface.callAPI("api_url").enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
                    RLProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
                    RLProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i actually found the solution as View stub does not inflate the whole layout i used dialog and assigned the loading layout to the dialog as following

```
 dialog=new Dialog(context, R.style.AppTheme_FullScreenDialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
    
    dialog.show();
```

after the request is performed

```
dialog.dissmis();
```